# Page Break in SubReports in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

**Description**
I have Crystal report with Sub Reports in Detail Section of Main Report.
The sub reports are dynamic (n number depends upon Data in Data source)
Each sub report contain Image (one image per sub report)

**Problem**
Sub reports are generating dynamically. let suppose 5 sub reports . The problem is the sub report footer is showing on last sub report.

**What I want** 
I want to display sub report footer on all sub reports .

**What I tried**

1. checked / unchecked Keep Together option on detail section of main
   report
2. checked / unchecked Keep Object Together on Sub Report
3. Page Break after 1 Record Option on Sub report Expert Section